# selectOneMenu value null when using selectItems from a different backing bean

Tags: java, jsf

I have a form where I create a user. In my form, I have multiple properties for that user (I actually use a User object for the retainment of data on submit to the backing bean)

**create.xhtml**

```
            <h:form>
                <h:outputLabel for="user_name" value="Name:" />
                <h:inputText id="user_name" value="#{createUserView.newUser.username}" />

                <br/><br/>

                <h:outputLabel for="user_password" value="Default Password*:" />
                <h:inputSecret id="user_password" value="#{createUserView.newUser.password}"></h:inputSecret><br/><br/>

                <h:outputLabel for="user_organization" value="Organization:" />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="user_organization" disabled="true" value="#{createUserView.newUser.organizationId}">
                    <f:selectItems 
                        value="#{organizationBean.allOrganizations}" 
                        var="org"
                        itemLabel="#{org.organizationName}"
                        itemValue="#{org.id}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu><br/><br/>

                <h:commandButton value="Create" action="#{createUserView.createNewUser}" />
            </h:form>
```

**CreateUserView**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "createUserView")
@RequestScoped
public class CreateUserView {

    private UserServices userSerivces;
    private User newUser;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{organizationBean}") 
    private OrganizationBean organizationBean;

    public CreateUserView() {
        newUser = new User();
        userSerivces = new UserServices();
    }

    public void createNewUser() {       
        userSerivces.createNewUser(newUser);
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**OrganizationBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "organizationBean")
@RequestScoped
public class OrganizationBean {

    private List<Organization> allOrganizations;
    private OrganizationServices orgServices;

    public OrganizationBean() {
        orgServices = new OrganizationServices();
        allOrganizations = orgServices.retrieveAllOrganizations();
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

The issue here is that when I reference the newUser object in the backing bean, the organizationId value is null.

I assume this is because OrganizationBean (excuse the confusing in naming, refactoring) is either not rendered for my current view or I need to somehow inject.

I've tried a managed property in the CreateUserView backing bean that references the OrganizationBean, but no luck. The organizationID value in the newUser object is null.

Do I need to populate a list in the CreateUserView bean using the OrganizationBean injection, so that it has it's own list it can render?

What am I missing? Feeling foolish.

JSF 2.0

Comment: Running into an issue is not foolish, can happen to anyone. Not creating a [mcve] when requested in [ask] sort of is. Not providing one makes helping for us difficult

Comment: What is the scope type of `OrganizationBean` ?

Comment: Do you have a converter for `Organization`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I will update as soon as I get access to my code

Comment: @OscarPérez - I do not have a converter for that object, no.

Comment: So I've run into a similar issue now with another bean, using a similar pattern. I've used a list generated in another Bean1 to populate a collection selection tag in primefaces that is in Bean2. This list is correctly displayed. When I hit the action button in the view, the list of selections from that collection in Bean2 is empty. It's almost like the fact I used a backing bean to populate the collection that isn't the same as the selection value is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as stated in the comments is that you don't have a `Converter` for your `Organization` class.

You must have it in order to know what `Organization` matches every `SelectItem`. The converter must be something like:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Organization.class, value = "organizationConverter")
public class OrganizationConverter implements Converter
{

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String id)
{
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id))
    {
        return null;
    }
    // Convert id to an Organizacion
    return organization;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o)
{
    if (o instanceof Organization)
    {
        return ...;//Convert organization to id
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

And then in your `selectonemenu`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="user_organization" disabled="true" value="#{createUserView.newUser.organizationId}" 
                converter="organizationConverter">
```

Comment: Just realized I forgot to override the toString method on the object. Let me check.

Comment: Yeah, so far the backing bean has not correctly obtained the value from the converter. I've debugged this, no solution yet. getAsObject is not called at any point, which is odd.